# lightning-input-field is not showing in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Can any help me why lightning input field is not displaying in the page. Also am getting `You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access`

**html:**

```
<div class="slds-p-around_xx-large">
<lightning-tabset variant="vertical">
    <lightning-tab label="Family Name">
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
            <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_small" title="Section 1">
                    Residency
                </span>
            </h3>
            <div class="slds-section__content">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    <template for:each={familyName} for:item="field" for:index="index">
                        <div class={sectionLayout} key={field.fieldAPI}>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name={field.fieldAPI} required={field.required}>
                            </lightning-input-field>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Parent/Guardian">
        Two Content !
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Students">
        Three Content !
    </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>

 </div>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class Enrollment extends LightningElement {
   @track enrollmentId;

@track familyName = [
  {fieldAPI: 'Name', required:true },
  { fieldAPI:'Home_Phone__c', required:true}
 ];
}
```

Meta XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
```

Comment: Check if u have access to that object??

Answer (score 1):

Athough you have System Administration privileges, please check if you have Write permission over the custom field field.fieldAPI in Setup / Users / Profiles / System Administration...

Sometimes in the creation of one field we don't give explicit Read/Write access to the field, so even an Administrator can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the `lighning-input-field` docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation):

> Use the lightning-input-field component in lightning-record-edit-form to display and edit the value of a record field of a Salesforce object. Use the field-name attribute to specify the API field name.

You need to add a `lightning-record-edit-form` to your component, and set its `object-api-name` value.  To edit an existing record, set its `record-id` property as well.